# Rails loop break keeps looping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a method in my Trial model that take the last two digits of `season_year` and concats a unique number on the end generated from a count method.

It all works fine and dandy, except when i delete a previous record.

For example: Say I have created 1800, 1801 and 1802. When I delete 1800 and try to create a new record I get the following error.

```
CACHE  (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "trials" WHERE "trials"."season_year" BETWEEN $1 AND $2  [["season_year", "2018-01-01"], ["season_year", "2018-12-31"]]
CACHE Trial Exists (0.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "trials" WHERE "trials"."trial_number" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["trial_number", 1802], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

For some reason it keeps looping the above.

What my desired outcome is for it to check if number exists, if it does move on to the next one, but for some reason it doesn't work when a previous record is deleted.

What I'd like it to do is start at 00 every time to check if a number has been used. if it has, move on to the next one. ie. 01

**Model**

```
class Trial < ApplicationRecord
before_create :create_trial_number

def count_records_from_same_year
    self.class.where(season_year: (season_year.beginning_of_year..season_year.end_of_year)).count
  end

  def create_trial_number
    loop do
      year = (season_year).strftime("%y")
      self.trial_number = year.concat(sprintf '%02d', count_records_from_same_year)
      break unless self.class.where(trial_number: self.trial_number).exists?
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What I'd like it to do is start at 00 every time to check if a number has been used. if it has, move on to the next one. ie. 01

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the code you posted does mutate any value to advance the loop? I assume you'd need to add a `self.season_year += 1` before the end of the block to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

Your method of creating a unique ID for the trial is highly ineffective.

You can use the id from the `trials` table as a unique identifier for the individual trial.

Alternatively you can let the database create an automatically incrementing column. MySQL uses the [AUTO_INCREMENT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) keyword, Postgres uses the concept of sequences.